# QtCreator runtime problems

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator

I'm writing a small application in qtcreator that uses opengl shader verion 3.3.
The application compiles fine, but when I run it from the ide the QGLFormat.getMajorVersion() returns 1.
 The interesting thing is that when I run the executable from the command line or the file manager it runs fine.. the function returns the expected 3.. The os I'm using is openSUSE 12.2.I have checked, the value of PATH is the same in QtCreator as in the cli..
Any ideas why this may be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, the value of PATH in Run Environment was correct, but the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH was missing the path to the 32bit libraries(/usr/lib).

Comment: weird.. in general you don't need to add `/usr/lib` anywhere.